# Using bash to copy contents of row in one file to specific character location in another file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, pipe

I'm new to bash and need help to copy Row 2 onwards from one file into a specific position (150 characters in) in another file. Through looking through the forum, I've found a way to include specific text listed at this position:

sed -i 's/^(.{150})/\1specifictextlisted/' destinationfile.txt

However, I can't seem to find a way to copy content from one file into this.

Basically, I'm working with these 2 starting files and need the following output:

File 1 contents:

> Sequence
>   AAAAAAAAAGGGGGGGGGGGCCCCCCCCCTTTTTTTTT

File 2 contents:

> chr2
>   tccccagcccagccccggccccatccccagcccagcctatccccagcccagcctatccccagcccagccccggccccagccccagccccggccccagccccagccccggccccagccccggccccatccccggccccggccccatccccggccccggccccggccccggccccggccccatccccagcccagccccagccccatccccagcccagccccggcccagccccagcccagccccagccacagcccagccccggccccagccccggcccaggcccagcccca

Desired output contents:

> chr2
>   tccccagcccagccccggccccatccccagcccagcctatccccagcccagcctatccccagcccagccccggccccagccccagccccggccccagccccagccccggccccagccccggccccatccccggccccggccccatccccgAAAAAAAAAGGGGGGGGGGGCCCCCCCCCTTTTTTTTTgccccggccccggccccggccccggccccatccccagcccagccccagccccatccccagcccagccccggcccagccccagcccagccccagccacagcccagccccggccccagccccggcccaggcccagcccca

Can anybody put me on the right track to achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` for that:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a=$2;next}{print $1, substr($2, 0, 149) "" a "" substr($2, 150)}' file1 file2
```

Explanation:

```
# Total row number == row number in file
# This is only true when processing file1
NR==FNR {
    a=$2 # store column 2 in a variable 'a'
    next # do not process the block below
}
# Because of the 'next' statement above, this
# block gets only executed for file2
{
    # put 'a' in the middle of the second column and print it
    print $1, substr($2, 0, 149) "" a "" substr($2, 150)
}
```

I assume that both files contain only a single line, like in your example.

---

Edit: In comments you said that the files actually spread two lines, in that case you can use the following awk script:

```
# usage: awk -f this_file.awk file1 file2

# True for the second line in each file
FNR==2 {
    # Total line number equals line number in file
    # This is only true while we are processing file1
    if(NR==FNR) {
        insert=$0 # Store the string to be inserted in a variable
    } else {
        # Insert the string in file1
        # Assigning to $0 will modify the current line
        $0 = substr($0, 0, 149) "" insert "" substr($0, 150)
    }
}

# Print lines of file2 (line 2 has been modified above)
NR!=FNR
```

Comment: Thank you for that example. I apologise but the formatting of the file I copied and pasted in initially showed file 1 contents as a single line, but it's actually 2 lines (edited in main post). Likewise, file 2 contains an initial line with "Chr2" before the sequence line below. I've input your above code with my filenames in place of file1 and file2, but the output remains unchanged. Should I be modifying anything else in your code to make it function correctly?

Comment: Assuming you have only one line after the sequence header, simply add a condition like `!/^>/` before the opening brace on the last block, and add `/^>/` after the closing brace to pass through and print the sequence header.

Comment: Good morning! :) Sorry I was sleeping. I will fix this when I arrive at work

Answer (score 1):

If the file is really huge instead of just 327 characters you might want to use dd:

```
dd if=chr2 bs=1 count=150 status=none of=destinationfile.txt
tr -d '\n' < Sequence >> destinationfile.txt
dd if=chr2 bs=1 skip=150 seek=189 status=none of=destinationfile.txt
```

189 is 150+length of `Sequence`.

Comment: Should the final parameter be `of=destinationfile.txt` or do you mean to have two different output files?

Comment: @tripleee yes of course, thanks for spotting it and that cat became unneccesary.

Comment: `tr` cannot read a file argument, you need to use input redirection. But yes, `cat` on a single file is always useless.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash and read one char at the time from the file:

```
i=1
while read -n 1 -r; do
    echo -n "$REPLY"
    let i++
    if [ $i -eq 150 ]; then
        echo -n "AAAAAAAAAGGGGGGGGGGGCCCCCCCCCTTTTTTTTT"
    fi
done < chr2 > destinationfile.txt
```

This simply reads a char, echos it and increments the counter. If the counter is 150 it echos your sequence. You can replace the echo with a `cat file | tr -d '\n'`. Just make sure to remove any newlines, like here with `tr`. That is also why I use `echo -n` so it doesn't add any.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tested your code partially successfully here: `i=1; while read -n 1 -r; do echo -n $REPLY; let i++; if [ $i -eq 150 ]; then echo -n "AAAAAAAAAGGGGGGGGGGGCCCCCCCCCTTTTTTTTT"; fi;done < file2 > file1` Is it possible to achieve this without including the sequence "AAAAAAAAAGGGGGGGGGGGCCCCCCCCCTTTTTTTTT"? As it stands, I'm able to achieve the same thing with `sed -i 's/^(.{150})/\1AAAAAAAAAGGGGGGGGGGGCCCCCCCCCTTTTTTTTT/' file2` but the point is to take it from row 2 of a separate file and not specify in-code as I will be using this with many files with different sequences.

Comment: you can strip the newline by adding `| tr -d '\n'` after it. My other answer should work for that too.